# Flutter Listview not scrolling to down by programatically

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple chat app I need to scroll to bottom of list view when data loads but its not going to bottom.

My code

```
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  void connectsocket() {
    userId = Provider.of<UserController>(context, listen: false)
        .userdata
        .sId
        .toString();

    try {
      socket = IO.io(ApiUrl.chatUrl, <String, dynamic>{
        'transports': ['websocket'],
        'autoConnect': true,
        'force new connection': true,
      });

      socket.connect();

      socket.on('connect', (_) {
        print('connect: ${socket.id}');

        socket.emit('joinRoom', {'user': userId, 'chatroom': widget.roomid});

        socket.on('getRoom', (data) {
          setState(() {
            messageList = data['data']['messages'];
          });
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
            _scrollController.animateTo(
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
              curve: Curves.easeOut,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            );
          });
        });

        socket.on('message', (data) {
          setState(() {
            messageList.add(data['data']);
            messageList = Set.of(messageList).toList();
          });
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

ListView.

```
   SizedBox(
                  width: size.width * 0.95,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: messageList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Card(
                              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                              ),
                              elevation: 2,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  messageList[index]['message'],
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                ),
```

When I get the message list I simply set data in a list and make the controller go down after 1 second but it's not scrolling down. I try to set the height etc but nothing is working.

Comment: can you try calling the scroll function manually to check if scrolling works or not [without socket ]

Comment: Have you tried to set reverse = true in the list view builder widget?